# how to create vm scaling count 1 dynamically using java script

Tags: javascript, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I have created window-server vm scale set.
I have written one application separately, on my request i want to create vm instance count to 1 ,via manual scale in azure portal ,its possible however i am looking through api i want to create vm instance and once its done i want to delete the vm,is it possible?please suggest/advise.
Thanks in advance.

`"capacity": {
"minimum": "1",
"maximum": "1",
"default": "1"
},`

Answer (score 0):

By using the **capacity** property under the **SKU** parameter, you can determine the number of instances that need to be provisioned while creating the VMSS, you can refer to the below sample example that was mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-scale-sets/create-or-update?tabs=JavaScript#create-a-custom-image-scale-set-from-an-unmanaged-generalized-os-image.):

```js
const { ComputeManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-compute");
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to Create or update a VM scale set.
 *
 * @summary Create or update a VM scale set.
 * x-ms-original-file: specification/compute/resource-manager/Microsoft.Compute/stable/2022-03-01/ComputeRP/examples/virtualMachineScaleSetExamples/VirtualMachineScaleSet_Create_CustomImageFromAnUnmanagedGeneralizedOsImage.json
 */
async function createACustomImageScaleSetFromAnUnmanagedGeneralizedOSImage() {
  const subscriptionId = "{subscription-id}";
  const resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup";
  const vmScaleSetName = "{vmss-name}";
  const parameters = {
    location: "westus",
    overprovision: true,
    sku: { name: "Standard_D1_v2", capacity: 3, tier: "Standard" },
    upgradePolicy: { mode: "Manual" },
    virtualMachineProfile: {
      networkProfile: {
        networkInterfaceConfigurations: [
          {
            name: "{vmss-name}",
            enableIPForwarding: true,
            ipConfigurations: [
              {
                name: "{vmss-name}",
                subnet: {
                  id: "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{existing-virtual-network-name}/subnets/{existing-subnet-name}",
                },
              },
            ],
            primary: true,
          },
        ],
      },
      osProfile: {
        adminPassword: "{your-password}",
        adminUsername: "{your-username}",
        computerNamePrefix: "{vmss-name}",
      },
      storageProfile: {
        osDisk: {
          name: "osDisk",
          caching: "ReadWrite",
          createOption: "FromImage",
          image: {
            uri: "http://{existing-storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{existing-container-name}/{existing-generalized-os-image-blob-name}.vhd",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const client = new ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);
  const result = await client.virtualMachineScaleSets.beginCreateOrUpdateAndWait(
    resourceGroupName,
    vmScaleSetName,
    parameters
  );
  console.log(result);
}

createACustomImageScaleSetFromAnUnmanagedGeneralizedOSImage().catch(console.error);
```

**Note**: Copied the above example code from the published azure documentation.